# how to increaase selection margin width in qmenubar

Tags: qt

i tried to set the spacing of the item in qmenubar to 16 pixel and the left margin as 8 px. using the styleguide i fixed the spacing and left margin .

```
"QMenuBar { \
                            padding-left:-9px; \
                            spacing: 16px; \
                            background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #B0B4B3, stop:0.5 #D4D5D4, stop:1 #FEFEFE); \
                            border-bottom-color: rgb(26,131,212); \
                        } \
                        QMenuBar::item { \
                            background: transparent;  \
                        } \
                        QMenuBar::item:selected { \
                                           background: qconicalgradient(cx:0, cy:0.5, angle: 90,\
                                                            fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0 rgb(29,146,236), stop:1 rgb(65, 167,243)); color:rgb(255,255,255); \
                        } \
                    ";
```

but i dont know how to increase the selection width or margin of the item . if the spacing between the unselected item is 16 px. the selected one should be 12 . four pixels of left and right margin i have to increase when the item is selected. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what exactly you want to achive.. do you want to enlarge selected menu bar so the other will move away from it?

Anyway - you can change selection margin for ::item and ::item:selected. I came up with trick where you set bigger margin for item and lesser for selected - it looks like it enlarges the background, although text is not changed(you can change font-size if you want)

```
QMenuBar::item
{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: blue;
}

QMenuBar::item:selected
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background: blue;
}
```